# Unable to parse Connection String in Azure Cloud Storage

Tags: android, parsing, azure-blob-storage

I have an android app and i want to download blob storage from Azure.I have a connection String but when i try to parse it ,my app gives me error and my app crash.How can i solve this?

[Github Link](https://github.com/berkkarabacak/Mspproje)

Activity which parses connection string:

```
package com.berkkarabacak.mspproje;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobContainer;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.ListBlobItem;

public class Checkactivity extends ActionBarActivity {
String tcnumara;
    public static final String ConnectionString =
            "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;"
                    + "AccountName=CENSORED;"
                    + "AccountKey=CENSORED";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.checkheartbeat);

        try
        {
            // Retrieve storage account from connection-string.
           CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(ConnectionString);

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Output the stack trace.
           e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    }
```

Logcat:

```
04-14 14:32:02.598  27372-27372/com.berkkarabacak.mspproje E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.berkkarabacak.mspproje, PID: 27372
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLOutputFactory;
            at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.Utility.<clinit>(Utility.java:120)
            at com.microsoft.azure.storage.CloudStorageAccount.parse(CloudStorageAccount.java:239)
            at com.berkkarabacak.mspproje.Checkactivity.onCreate(Checkactivity.java:36)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6283)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.berkkarabacak.mspproje-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.Utility.<clinit>(Utility.java:120)
            at com.microsoft.azure.storage.CloudStorageAccount.parse(CloudStorageAccount.java:239)
            at com.berkkarabacak.mspproje.Checkactivity.onCreate(Checkactivity.java:36)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6283)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 17 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
04-14 14:32:04.528  27372-27372/com.berkkarabacak.mspproje I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 27372 SIG: 9
```

Comment: btw if you want i can give AccountName+ AccountKey.Not that important storage anyway

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at your [gradle build file](https://github.com/berkkarabacak/Mspproje/blob/master/app/build.gradle) it looks like you're using the [Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java) Storage library rather than the [Android](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-android) Storage library. If you take a look at the GitHub landing page for the Android storage library there should be directions for importing the Android aar via your gradle build.

Comment: It works now,i was careless thinking Java Storage library would work.You are great emily :)